# I have a spatial line feature and want to offset the line to 3m in direction left. I am using R as a platform which function can be used?

Tags: r, spatial

could not find any function to offset a line in r

I tired function like buffer but it gives polygon output. And many of the function I tried to use and searched in google are deprecated. what function can be used? any possible solution or function to offset a line